# What is a homogeneous magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, terminology, notation

What does it mean when one says that a magnetic field is a homogeneous magnetic field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general understanding of this term is a magnetic field which has a constant magnitude and direction over the entire region of interest.

If the author wants to allow for a changing direction instead (but keeping the constant magnitude), then that must be indicated explicitly.